# How to adapt LilyPond code to work in LaTeX?

Tags: lilypond

Is there a way to override the content of the LilyPond file, e.g. as an option in the LaTeX command? In particular the page things like page size and fonts. And is it possible to call up information like copyright in the LaTeX file?

MWE:

LaTeX

```
\documentclass[
ngerman
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=20mm,right=20mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
    \sffamily\bfseries

    \section*{First song}
    We will sing together....
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \lilypondfile[staffsize=12]{MWE.ly}
    \end{figure}
    

    
\end{document}
```

LilyPond

```
%% LilyPond-Datei erzeugt durch Denemo Version 2.5.0

%%http://www.gnu.org/software/denemo/

\version "2.22"

CompactChordSymbols = {}
#(define DenemoTransposeStep 0)
#(define DenemoTransposeAccidental 0)
DenemoGlobalTranspose = \void {}
titledPiece = {}
AutoBarline = {}
AutoEndMovementBarline = \bar "|."

% The music follows

MvmntIVoiceI = {
         c'4 d' e' f'\AutoBarline
         g' a' b' b'\AutoBarline
         a' g' f' e'\AutoBarline
         d' c' c' d'\AutoBarline
%5
         e' f' g' a'\AutoBarline
         b' b' a' g'\AutoBarline
         f' e' d' c' \AutoEndMovementBarline
}


MvmntIVoiceILyricsVerseI = \lyricmode { 
foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar 
}



MvmntIVoiceIVerseIContext = \context Lyrics = MvmntIVoiceIVerseI \lyricsto MvmntIVoiceI \MvmntIVoiceILyricsVerseI



%Default Score Layout
\header{DenemoLayoutName = "Default Score Layout"
        instrumentation = \markup { \with-url #'"scheme:(d-BookInstrumentation)" "Full Score"}
        }

\header {
tagline = \markup {"/home/bjoern/Nextcloud/Bj\303\266rns Cloud/Melanie und Bj\303\266rn/Hochzeit/Kirchenheft/MWE/MWE.denemo" on \simple #(strftime "%x" (localtime (current-time)))}
     dedication = ##f
     title = \markup \with-url #'"scheme:(DenemoSetTitles \"ScoreTitles\" 'title #t)"  {MWE}
     subtitle = ##f
     subsubtitle = ##f
     instrument = ##f
     poet = \markup \with-url #'"scheme:(DenemoSetTitles \"ScoreTitles\" 'poet #t)"  {poet}
     composer = \markup \with-url #'"scheme:(DenemoSetTitles \"ScoreTitles\" 'composer #t)"  {composer}
     meter = ##f
     arranger = ##f
     tagline = ##f
     copyright = \markup \with-url #'"scheme:(DenemoSetTitles \"ScoreTitles\" 'copyright #t)"  {copyright}
     piece = ##f
     opus = ##f

        }
#(set-default-paper-size "a4")
#(set-global-staff-size 18)
\paper {

       }

\score { %Start of Movement
          <<

%Start of Staff
\new Staff = "Part 1"  << 
 \new Voice = "MvmntIVoiceI"  { 
  \clef treble    \key c \major    \time 4/4   \MvmntIVoiceI
                        } %End of voice

                        >> %End of Staff

        \new Lyrics = MvmntIVoiceIVerseI

        \MvmntIVoiceIVerseIContext

          >>

       } %End of Movement
```

This produces this output:
[image: MWE]

Answer (score 2):

[lyluatex](https://ctan.tetaneutral.net/support/lyluatex/lyluatex.pdf) (as opposed to lilypond-book) does some of this. It passes the LaTeX page size to LilyPond, and there is a `pass-fonts` option to pass the fonts as well. See its documentation for details (look for "papersize" and "pass-fonts").

Passing information the other way is more complicated, but you could potentially use LilyPond's `--header` option to extract header fields, then import them into LaTeX. (My knowledge of LaTeX is too limited to give a full example.)